# Appending new data every day with Django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a Django project that has one model, Fund which holds the details about a particular fund (IE: fund_id, name, details, minimum, etc.).

```
class Fund(models.Model):
    name = ...
    details = ...
    minimum = ...
    # etc
```

However I want to create another model, lets call it FundPerformace that has a foreign key that links it to a fund. In FundPerformace I would like to add the date (DateTimeField) and its return for that date (IntegerField). However, I would like to add a new date and return everyday. Is there anyway that i can accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's define the `Fund`.

```
class Fund(models.Model):
    name = ...
    details = ...
    minimum = ...
    # etc
```

Second, created you need `FundPerformace`.

```
class FundPerformace (models.Model):
    fund_id = models.ForeignKey(Fund)
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

Maybe you need to use `crontab` to record the performance of the fund at regular time. You can see the fund of the change.